"Could not drop object .. because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint" but sp_fkeys comes back empty?
For a given table bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary I have used an INFORMATION_SCHEMA query to view referencing tables (from joining INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS, REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS, CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE, back to TABLE_CONSTRAINTS]. This came up empty.
But then the following error occurred anyways:

Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not drop object 'bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

So I searched and found this on SOF:
EXEC sp_fkeys 'bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary'

This also came up empty. Note: I also tried without the schema prefix.
Finally, I just looked at all foreign key constraints. There aren't any that in any way have to do with the LawAggregatedPipelineSummary table
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'


So then how can this mysterious referent be found?
Update here is a portion of my attempted FK finder query. I was not aware of sp_foreign_keys [and have been seeing "deprecated!" "deprecated" about those sp folks], so I tried to roll my own. I wonder where this query is going wrong (it's not finding the foreign key)
select 
    pk.*, rc.*,
    rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk
join 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
        on rc.unique_constraint_catalog = pk.table_catalog
        and rc.unique_constraint_schema = pk.table_schema
        and rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.constraint_name
join 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE pkc
        on pkc.table_catalog = pk.table_catalog
        and pkc.table_schema = pk.table_schema
        and pkc.table_NAME = pk.table_name


what does sys.foreign_keys show?

You can find your foreign key with this. select *  from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary')

@StrayCatDBA  Same results as I showed from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query: nothing relevant. Oh wait, actually one apparently is: it is from a unique constraint not a PK. I wonder if that's why my earlier query were not finding it

@SeanLange  Thanks - that does highlight the very last row of the four shown. I had looked at that row and not recognized it as a referent to the indicated table. It is actually a unique key but not a PK.  So i'll look further at what is happening in my query

Then it is a foreign key. Try this one. The first column will tell you the name of the table where the foreign key resides. You will need to remove that foreign key before you can drop your table. select TableName = object_name(parent_object_id)   , ReferencedTable = object_name(referenced_object_id)  , *  from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary')

It's probably the case that my query is driving the wrong direction: it should drive from the FK table to the constraints to the PK table not the other way around.  I'm going to fix it after a meeting starting now

Just use the query I already posted. It is using sys.foreign_keys which is not a deprecated table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 Part of the struggle you are having is those INFORMATION_SCHEMA cannot be trusted with schemas (and various other parts). That is even documented by MS that they can't be trusted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@SeanLange  I did likely find my error, need to use unique_constraint_name to refer back to the PK table. But yea, i'll look into using the sp_ instead. Feel free to make an answer

Use the proper schema views, eg
select name ForeignKeyName, object_schema_name(parent_object_id) SchemaName, object_name(parent_object_id) TableName
from sys.foreign_keys
where referenced_object_id = object_id('bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary')


Please don't post duplicate answers. If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer and then vote to close the other(s) as duplicates. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

The other question was closed as a duplicate of this question, which is odd as this question had no answers.  So I copied the answer from there to here.
